# Background task spontaneous completion C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, background-process, background-task

Register a background task:

```
    string myTaskName = "Task";

   foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        if (cur.Value.Name == myTaskName)
        {
           return;
        }

   await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

   BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder 
   { 
        Name = "Task", 
        TaskEntryPoint = "Background.Task"
   };
   taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, true));
   BackgroundTaskRegistration myFirstTask = taskBuilder.Register();
```

Background task is created in the Windows Runtime Component as a separate class:

```
public sealed class Task : IBackgroundTask 
        {
            public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
            {
                BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

//logic, send http get request, connect to db

                deferral.Complete();
            }
}
```

When it is time to perform task- it may run random number of times (1 - 15 times) and then spontaneously terminated and no longer starts,to solve this problem need to re-register task. What could be the reason?

VS show this error when i want run task:[image]

Comment: I don't know how's that in new Apps on Win 8.0/8.1, but on WinPhones, each task/job had some runtime limits: both max.memory usage AND max. single running time were limited. When any of those measures were exceeded, the task/job was  terminated and its schedule disabled until the application was re-run and the task was re-scheduled again from scratch. On WinPhone framework the limits were quite tight, <20 seconds and <30mb of memory,but that also depended on kind of the task/job. You may be observing a similar behavior here. If there are limits, be clearly noted on MSDN. Just a guess though.

Comment: Oh, and any unhandled exception that bubbled from the task/job also imediately resulted in its schedule to be cancelled.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, App on win phone 8.1.
It's not because of stress on memory. I concluded the toast notification instead of logic batskground task. And again there was an error :C

Comment: Reason is an argumentexception as you can See in your Screenshot.

Comment: @Jehof, No, it is not a reason. If background task is empty - i get this error too. Try/catch cant catch this error. I dont know how this error was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Phone periodic background tasks are executed at an interval of a minimum of 30 minutes.

> Windows has a built-in timer that runs background tasks in 15-minute intervals. **Note that on Windows Phone, the interval is 30 minutes.**

(Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If I were you I'd change the time interval to something more safe (such as 60 minutes) - you can always try smaller intervals later. And take a look at the `oneShot` flag, which is set to `true` in your case. Set it to `false` to make your task run more than once.

Also your exception does not look healthy. You said it even occurs with the background task being empty - you should fix that, just to be safe.

I'd suggest you to manually start and debug your backgorund task a couple of times using the lifecycle feature in Visual Studio. Maybe there are other things that cause your task to die.

But first check the interval.

Comment: Solve this problem : taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, FALSE));
OneShot must be false, and u can set time to 15 min.

Comment: Now that you've pointed it out I know what I wanted to add to my answer. When I saw your question I thought: "Oneshot is true - that can't be right", but totally forgot about it when posting my answer :) I'll edit the post to reflect that.